# Почему ответ response json 200, а не 201 как задумывалось? Запрос на регистрацию по номеру не отправляется

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import requests
import json

data = {
    "items": [
        {
            "path": "auth/login-or-register",
            "params": {
                "phone": "+79313664208",
                "retpath": "https://auto.ru/"
            }
        }
    ]
}

ru = requests.post("https://auth.auto.ru/login/?r=https%3A%2F%2Fauto.ru%2F", json=data)
```

Comment: 200 это значит все прошло отлично

Comment: Почему вы решили, что должно быть 201, а не 200?

Comment: @insolor, потому что    payload = {'phone_number':x}
    ru = requests.post("https://eda.yandex/api/v1/user/request_authentication_code", json=payload)
    при исполнении этого кода именно 201, и сообщение о реге приходит на номер.

Comment: @ИванИванычИванов, как связано апи яндакс еды и апи авто ру?

Comment: @insolor, Я бы хотел получить ответ, что делаю не так, а не ещё большее количество вопросов. Понимаю, что вы - человек опытный, и таких вопросов, от которых уже воротит, полно, но всё же прошу быть снисходительным.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что API разных сайтов, которые делали разные команды разработчиков, будет возвращать одинаковые коды? В чем проблема - проблема в том что не тот код (не тот, который вы ожидаете получить) или регистрация не происходит?

Comment: @insolor, да. Запрос на регистрацию не отправляется. Посмел предположить, что это как-то связано.

Comment: Насколько я вижу, у auto.ru нет открытого апи. Нужно смотреть что там возвращается в теле ответа, и в зависимости от этого уже думать что делать.